# Improper \spacefactor after switching to babel?

Tags: babel

After switching from `ngerman` package to babel with `ngerman` option, I get a  "improper \spacefactor" error on this text part: `$\glq$Kostendeckungsprinzip$\grq$`

Any idea where this error comes from?

Since I don't know where the error comes from, please allow me to post my entire config.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}


\usepackage{ragged2e} %justify blocksatz packet
%%
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% alle zuvor um per C zellen gleicher groesse zu ermoeglichen
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb} %mathesymbole durchschnittszeichen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{courier}
%hinzugefugt 
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{emptypage} %cleardoublepage ohne seitenzahl
%\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, maxcitenames=3, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber, dashed=false, firstinits=true, doi=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
%
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
%
\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
% Grafikzeugs
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}       
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[justification=centering, labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=10pt}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins} %tabellen bleiben in gliederungsebene
%
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                   % please use the style svind.ist with
                   % your makeindex program
%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
text text text $\glq$Kostendeckungsprinzip$\grq$ text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Surely `$\glq$` is wrong. Is there some guide out there that recommends this?

Comment: no, i figured that this is the way to do it. apparently i was wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather use `\enquote{Kostendeckungsprinzip}` from the `csquotes` package than those ('old-fashioned') `\glq` and `\grq` commands.

The main cause of the problem is that `\glq` etc. can't be used in math mode.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=german,babel]{csquotes}

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                   % please use the style svind.ist with
                   % your makeindex program
%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
text text text \glq Kostendeckungsprinzip\grq\ text text

text text text \enquote{Kostendeckungsprinzip} text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've removed some packages not needed for the code here